# Admin Notice is only localized when displaying the "Plugins" Backend Page

Tags: plugins, hooks, translation, localization

My plugin checks if a specific theme is activated. The check is hooked on `init`.

If the theme is not activated, it displays a warning, hooked on `admin_notices`.

*This works fine.*

Now I added localization support with the help of "Loco Translate" and `.mo` / `.po` files.

`load_plugin_textdomain`is hooked on `init`.

*This works too, translations are showing up.*

***Now it gets weird:***

My "Admin Notice" gets translated as expected, **but only** when opening `wp-admin/plugins.php`.
On any other backend-page the non-translated version appears.

My guess is it has something to do with the hook-order, but I can not figure out how to order the checks properly.

Some code, redacted for sanity:

```
<?php


namespace Me\MyPlugin;


class Bootstrapping
{

    public static function notifyOnMissingTheme(): void {

        if( ! self::ThemeIsActivated() ) {
            add_action('admin_notices', [self::class, '_echoThemeExistanceWarning']);
        }

    }

    public static function activateTranslationSupport() : void {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'language-domain', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages');
    }


    private static function ThemeIsActivated(): bool
    {
        $theme = wp_get_theme();

        if (!('My themes name' == $theme->name || 'My themes name' == $theme->parent_theme) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }


    static function _echoThemeExistanceWarning(): void {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-warning"><p>'. __('Notification from Plugin: Please activate the Theme for best experience with this plugin!', 'language-domain'). '</p></div>';
    }

}
```

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Plugin
Text Domain: language-domain
Domain Path: /languages
*/

namespace Me\MyPlugin;


add_action('init', [Bootstrapping::class, 'activateTranslationSupport']);
add_action('init', [Bootstrapping::class, 'notifyOnMissingTheme']);
```

Two screenshots for clarification:

[image]

[image]

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: The translations you loaded are for the text domain `management-plugin`, but the one you used with `__()` is `language-domain`. So which one is the correct text domain for your plugin? Is the former was just a typo in your post?

Comment: @SallyCJ That was just a typo in my post - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Revised because that `'__FILE__'` as in `dirname(plugin_basename('__FILE__'))`, was just a typo in the post/question.

But one thing you did not include in your post, is about how are you loading the `Bootstrapping` class, and where is the file located? Is it in a subfolder like `includes`, i.e.

```
your-plugin/
    includes/
        class-bootstraping.php
    languages/
        your-plugin.pot
    your-plugin.php (main plugin file)
```

If so, then you should ***not*** use `__FILE__` and instead, in the main plugin file, you can define a constant which stores the full absolute path to the main plugin file. E.g.

```php
define( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );

// I commented it out, but this is how I loaded the class:
//require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class-bootstraping.php';
```

Then from within your class, when you call `plugin_basename()`, pass the above constant. E.g.

```php
load_plugin_textdomain(
    'language-domain',
    false,
    dirname( plugin_basename( YOUR_PLUGIN_FILE ) ) . '/languages'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment/answer - these typos came from redacting the code for this post. Sorry again for that. As stated before, my code is running but the weird behaviour persists. I added two screenshots in my original post for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the issue was and as stated in my answer, I also got the same issue with your code, but it's gone after I used `__FILE__` instead of `'__FILE__'`. So double-check that in your *actual* class file - are you sure you are using `plugin_basename(__FILE__)`?

Comment: So, have you confirmed that the `'__FILE__'` typo only existed in your post and not the actual class file? If so, can you add the full code *exactly* as it is currently in that file?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The typo was only in my post. But still, there may be an issue with the whole path. I will try to debug it with xdebug tomorrow.

Comment: You might want to first check my revised answer.. :) Let me know!

Comment: You are the best! :-) Your revised answer made it clear that indeed Bootstrapping was called from a subfolder. Additionaly i've overlooked that load_plugin_textdomain expects a relative path. For me as beginner its sometimes quite confusing how path functions in wordpress work.

Using constants as suggested by you, solves my problem and the code works just fine now! Thanks alot!